# How can I prevent Ctrl+Shift from changing the text direction?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, right-to-left

In Windows 7 and 8, the following keyboard shortcuts exist when both left-to-right and right-to-left languages are installed:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> sets the text direction to right-to-left.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> sets the text direction to left-to-right.

This is a problem because they conflict with the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> shortcuts. (These are used to select the next/previous word, respectively.)

Besides removing the right-to-left languages from the system, **is there a way to disable these shortcuts**?

Comment: Which word processors? The keyboard shortcuts for left align and right align are usually `Ctrl + L` and `Ctrl + R`, respectively.

Comment: Notepad, for instance, although I would rather categorize it as self-inflicted pain rather than a word processor.

Comment: Is the RTL switch happening also when you have active `En` (English - United States) keyboard?

Comment: A [related MS thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/disable-ctrlshift-to-change-text-direction/bacc1e97-10db-4f33-9c59-e35ed942a267), but no solution there (yet)

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found how to disable the shortcut withing Windows,
but if you're open to using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), there's a workaround:

**Use AutoHotKey to map <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to be <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>**

No more RTL by mistake, and my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> works without problem. I don't yet know of any reason why I need RShift, so I'm happy with this so far.

AutoHotKey mapping syntax is simple on this one:

```
RShift::LShift
```

*Credit: Inspired by @gogowitsch in a comment on https://superuser.com/a/490244/93731*

Answer (score 1):

It also happens with Windows 10, MS Office 365 (Word, OneNote, PowerPoint, Outlook. Whatever the keyboard is `EN` or other. Any key combinations with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> can lead to mistakenly switch from Left-To-Right (LTR) to Right-To-Left (RTL) and vice versa (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, etc.)

It's a feature of Office when you have both RTL and LTR languages installed, and it seems it cannot be deactivated if you keep both types of languages installed.

You are lucky if you need only either RTL languages, or only LTR languages. Otherwise, no solution.

You can remove the languages from any Office application, below example is from MS Word, but it will impact other Office applications:

- File:

  [image: MS Word Office 365 File menu]
- Click "Options":

  [image: MS Word Office 365 File menu]
- Click "Language". Here I have decided to remove the RTL languages (Arabic), to keep only LTR languages (English, French):

  [image: MS Word Office 365 Options]
- Then restart all your Office applications and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is no more an issue:

  [image: Restart your Office applications]

NB: credits to [Benjamin](https://superuser.com/a/1324851/1007423) and [TKWatcher](https://superuser.com/a/991908/1007423).

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me on Windows 11 w/ Office365 when the "Advanced Key Settings" failed to make any difference.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Language -> Advanced settings -> Advanced Key Settings -> Change Key Sequence... and change the settings to Not Assigned

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried, this doesn't actually stop the RTL change from happening when I hit Ctrl+RightShift (and end up not hitting the left or right arrow)

Comment: I think this answer is valid for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i), but not for the question above.