# How to change the text direction on Windows?

Tags: windows, text-editing, right-to-left

Sometimes when I'm typing, text orientation changes from `LTR` to `RTL`, but I am not able to find any shortcut to change the text direction on Windows.

How can I change the text direction inside a text box or a text area?

Comment: After a lot of search, I was able to do this. Hold LeftCtrl then press LeftShift to make text LTR. Similarly, hold RightCtrl then press RightShift to make text RTL.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To switch between `RTL` (Right-To-Left) and `LTR` (Left-To-Right) text directions, you need to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> for `LTR`.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> for `RTL`.

To change the direction of the whole text, select all of it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) before changing the text direction.

Comment: Is there a way to disable these? The only times I hit them is by accident.

Comment: @naxa See [**How to disable Ctrl+Shift keyboard layout switch (for the same input language) in Windows?**](http://superuser.com/q/109066/138020)

Comment: Dear @amiregelz, unfortunately your link doesn't contain the solution. I've already disabled the Ctrl+Shift shortcut there, but the page is about keyboard layouts, not writing directions.

Comment: What if you only have a Left Ctrl and not a Right one?

Comment: This does not work for me, I do not have R2L enabled. Win7, MSWord 2013.

Comment: Minor correction / addition to the answer (at least for Windows 10): Which Control key you press doesn't matter. The Shift does, though. I frequently find myself pressing Control on the left and Shift on the right and then cursing and swearing until I press the right combo to get it back (which led me here for some definite answers).

Comment: this is a really poorly thought out key combo.  CTRL&SHIFT is hardly a rare combination, I would imagine that the vast majority of uses of this key combination are accidental.  (I tend to do it when I've been highlighting text by whole word for instance)

Comment: This worked for me in the Trilium Windows Desktop notes app. It's unfortunate because you often use CTRL-SHIFT-C key combination for cloning a note somewhere in the tree. I guess sometimes I must be clicking CTRL just that millisecond before I get to SHIFT. It was driving me nuts not knowing what was causing RTL text, so thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me. Windows 10 22H2

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to fix a similar issue - it turned out to be limited to Office applications (inc. Outlook) and was caused by having Hebrew listed as an editing language (*Options>Language>Choose Editing Languages*).

Removing it and restarting all Office applications solved the problem.

Comment: Welcome on board, I think you are unable to understand the Key Question, please read carefully before you compose the answer. Refer this link, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer.