# Reversed text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, text-editing, right-to-left

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the text direction on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/471692/how-to-change-the-text-direction-on-windows)

I was typing something in Chrome and all of a sudden, the text reversed. It was now typing Right-to-Left like Arabic instead of Left-to-Right. I tried elsewhere and it was fine. It only affected that particular textbox. After refreshing, everything was normal.

I think I might have hit some keys accidentally. Any idea how this happened and what I can do next time?

Comment: Is there any way to disable the hotkey, either in Chrome, or in Windows in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right-to-left editing mode must've been activated by a keyboard short-shortcut. In Chrome, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and in Firefox it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Just encountered this problem in Chrome on a Mac, and `Ctrl+LeftShift` fixed it for me.