# How to edit/create settings/shortcut/macro for enabling reversed text input direction in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, macros, input

I want to create a hotkey for the ability to insert a character without advancing the caret, i.e. write backwards.

Every search I tried on Google related to this functionality is of how to disable it, and all answers say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

This does not work for me, as it shouldn't, because I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> for general mapping of shortcuts. If it once did change text direction on my system, I have at some point disabled it. It probably also related to changing keyboard layout for different languages, as I saw that topic being brought up in relation to this, and I use three language layouts on Windows, but I switch between those with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> for reverse iteration).

I cannot find any information on how this functionality would be enabled through navigating Windows 10 settings, nor where the correlated system value could be reached through regedit or other avenue. The closest thing I found is [this mention of a possible `inputRTL` value](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/text-that-is-typed-by-using-the-right-to-left-reading-order-is-displayed-by-using-the-left-to-right-reading-order-in-the-sent-message-pane-in-lync-2010-32da7600-79c6-42c3-ae4b-471d2d8d7be8) on a topic about Lync 2010.

I assume what I want could be otherwise be achieved by having a AutoHotkey script running that would enable something simple like, if a key is held while a character has been typed, move caret back one step. But I'd rather not have to rely on AutoHotkey for this ability.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no *global* keyboard shortcut for RTL-LTR, other than, perhaps, changing keyboard layout. https://superuser.com/questions/471692/how-to-change-the-text-direction-on-windows The direction of entry is set in each application. For example, LibreOffice Writer (and likely MS Word) uses those L/R Ctlr-Shift shortcuts, and Notepad++ and MS Notepad, MS Edge and Firefox ignore them.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I do not know why you linked me that question. Read the second and third sentence of my post.